# Автоматическая загрузка mp3 файла в браузере

Tags: flash, mp3, actionscript

Добрый день! Подскажите пожалуйста, как можно сделать автоматическую загрузку mp3 файла (flash, html5?)... Если установлен плагин Quicktime (и, возможно, некоторые другие), то при нажатии на ссылку начинается воспроизведение. Конечно, можно в браузере нажать "Сохранить как...", но есть ли способ удобнее?

Ссылка на файл уникальна для каждого IP, поэтому всё нужно делать на стороне клиента. Пока у меня единственный вариант - Flash, но, во-первых, я с ним не знаком, во-вторых, я  не уверен, можно ли с его помощью просто скачать файл в папку загрузок (с минимумом действий со стороны пользователя).

Идеальным вариантом был бы небольшой менеджер загрузок на Flash, с одновременной загрузкой нескольких файлов, прогресс-барами и возможностью остановить закачку. Может что-то такое уже есть в интернете? Если нет, подскажите, где можно найти инструкции?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашёл пример Flash загрузчика файлов в [одном из примеров по Adobe Flash](http://help.adobe.com/support/documentation/en/flash/10/FlashPlatformAS3DevGuideExamples.zip) (папка FileIO в архиве, flash pro version). Вдруг кому-то ещё будет нужно. Вопрос закрыт.